# Enumeration in theorem environment

Tags: formatting, lists, theorems, enumerate

I am puzzled with a formating question.
I was asked to change that the enumeration gives me italic numbers in the theorem environment to non-italic ones. How can customize enumeration, such that it will not adopt the italic format of the theorem environment? Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem/) makes it easy to customize lists, so I’ll use that. The code below is just for a single list, but you could use `\setlist` to make it global. See [the documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    The following are equivalent:
    \begin{enumerate}[font=\normalfont]
        \item $1 + 1$
        \item $2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]